# Prevent on cascade delete on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have added a foreign key to a value in my db, so when you try to delete a user with that value it wont allow you to delete it, but, i cant figure it out how to manage this via blade template, im getting the laravel error:

(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

So, i got this, but doesnt work:

```
if ($user->delete()) {
                    $request->session()->flash('success', 'User Deleted.');
                    return redirect()->route('admin/user.getall');
                }  else {
                    $request->session()->flash('danger', 'Unable to delete user with Value.');
                        return redirect()->route('admin/user.getall');
                }
```

What can i do in this case?, i dont want to remove the key or i dont want to change to false on stric db, i got on true, i need this, any other way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some exception  handelling

```
try{
  $user->delete();
}
catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
      $request->session()->flash('danger', 'Unable to delete user with Value.');
      return redirect()->route('admin/user.getall');
    }
```

Comment: Not working in my case, Laravel 5.4, do i need to add something?

Comment: No error, it just redirects me to getall, also it doesnt delete on normal users.

Comment: Its working now!, just needed to add the variable to the view to show the message.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of a foreign key is that you cannot delete data from the database, as long as there is data linked to it (via the foreign key). So you first have to remove all data linked to that user, before you can remove the user.

Please have a look at [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) I believe Laravel can do allot more for you than you are currently using! And a [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14)

Comment: No, the idea is just to prevent and send a message to the user.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. The question itself is rather unclear as well: I assumed you wanted to know why you are getting the error and how to solve it, but it seems that's not what you want.

Comment: I need to display a message to the user, i was able to do it on here: